# Setting Background of Non-Editable JComboBox in a specific LookAndFell

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jcombobox, look-and-feel

I am using this specific LookAndFeel:

```
    PlasticLookAndFeel.setPlasticTheme(new com.jgoodies.looks.plastic.theme.SkyBluer());
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new com.jgoodies.looks.plastic.PlasticLookAndFeel());
```

I used this code to set background of a editable JComboBox named component:

```
    ComboBoxEditor editor = component.getEditor();
    JTextField textField = (JTextField) editor.getEditorComponent();
    textField.setBackground(color);
```

And the result is that:

[image]

If I use the same code for a NON-editable combobox, nothing happens:

[image]

And If I use this code for a NON-editable combobox:

```
    ((JComboBox)component).setBackground(color);
```

The result is that the color extrapolates the component size. Like this Figure:

[image]

1) Does anyone know a way of setting the background for Non-Editable combobox without extrapolate the size for this specific LookAndFell?

Comment: to try to change in UIManager.put("ComboBox.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.yellow)); or ComboBox.selectionBackground, ComboBox.selectionForeground, but proper of ways is usage of Renderer for this job, start with BasicComboBoxRenderer, then you can to use ListCellRenderer, more info in Oracle tutorials JList, JTable, JTree and JComboBox, Renderes concept is similair for all JComponents, to read docs for jgoodies if is there user own Renderer or accepted standard Renderers concept or their combinations

Comment: I Tried to use this code  UIManager.put("ComboBox.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.yellow)) now but this changed all comboboxs background and the color extrapolate the size too.